# How to iterate over an array with underscore.js having the previous value as well as the current?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, iteration, underscore.js

Is there any easy magical combination of functions from underscore (lo-dash) to achieve the following algorithm:

```
var arr = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25];
var result = [];
for(var i = 1, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var current = arr[i];
    var previous = arr[i-1];
    result[i-1] = current - previous;
}
// result == [3, 5, 7, 9]
```

with a simpler syntax:

```
var arr = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25];
var result = _.???(arr, function(current, previous) {
    return current - previous;
}
```

?

Notes:

1. that I don't want to roll my own function, I'd rather use a combination of existing methods.
2. obviously my arrays contain objects not numbers and the result may or may not be a list of  numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `_.map()` and use the `i` and collection it gives you.

```
var arr = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25];
var result = _.map(arr, function(curr, i, arr) {
    return i ? curr - arr[i-1] : null;
}).slice(1);
```

I've returned `null` in the first iteration, then sliced it away at the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/8aZnp/

---

Technically `_.reduce()` can give you the last and current items if you always return the current. It's a little bit of a hackish way of using `_.reduce`, but it works.

```
var arr = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25];
var result = [];
_.reduce(arr, function (last, curr) {
    result.push(curr - last);
    return curr;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8aZnp/1/

Comment: If you have _ES5_ supported, `reduce` is natively available in _JavaScipt_ and would work with the exact same function as you gave `_.reduce` (the same `map` would probably work too)

Comment: @PaulS.: AFAIK Underscore will use the native functions if they're available.

Comment: I'm going with `reduce` it looks nice and easy. I always use methods from a library, because they take care of polyfilling for me when not in a compliant environment. (The other day I tried `_.slice` accidentally :)

Comment: Note: this usage of `reduce` is undocumented in `underscore`, but documented in `lo-dash`: "_If accumulator is not provided the first element of the collection will be used as the initial accumulator value._"

Answer (score 1):

Another way I figured out is:

```
var arr = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25];
_.map(_.zip(_.rest(arr , 1), _.first(arr, arr.length - 1)), function(pair) {
    var current = pair[0];
    var previous = pair[1];
    return current - previous;
});
```

But this solution is `O(4n)` (given `map`, `zip`, `rest` and `first` are linear) and very verbose.